# NSDictionary with byte and objects as key value

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, implicit-conversion

I have an `NSDictionary` object that holds (key,value) pairs of (byte, Custom Class) where `byte` is `typedef unsigned char byte`.

The following is my code

in `Mos6502.h`

```
@interface Mos6502 : NSObject {
@private
    Instruction *currentInstruction;
}

@property NSDictionary *instructions;
```

in `Mos6502.m`, in the `init` method I filled the dictionary with a byte (unsigned char) that represents the instruction's opcode, and the value is an instance of the instruction's class. Like the following

```
instructions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      0x00, [[BRK alloc] init],
                      // rest of the instructions
                      nil];
```

Where BRK and other instruction classes inherit from a base class called Instruction.

In the same file, but in a method where i need to get the current instruction, the following line gives me the error:

`currentInstruction = [instructions objectAtKey:[mem readByteAt:(PC++)]];`

with the following error message,

`Implicit conversion of 'byte' (aka 'unsigned char') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC`

and when I try to put instead of `[mem readByteAt:(PC++)]` a number such as `0x00` I don't get an error anymore.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may store a char in an `NSNumber` then store that, but the value in a collection class must be an Obj-C value.

also... the key must support `NSCopying.`

```
instructions = @{@(0x00) : [[BRK alloc] init] };
```

or

```
  instructions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                  [NSNumber numberWithChar:0x00], [[BRK alloc] init],
                  // rest of the instructions
                  nil];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is:

- 0x00 isn't an NSObject, you can only put NSObjects into a dictionary. You can 'box' a primitive (make into NSNumber equivalent) by putting @ in front of it.  Try @0x00.
- I think you have the key and value the wrong way around. Unlike the rest of the world Apple puts the Object before the Key in the dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys method.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a byte as a key in an NSDictionary. You have to use an object. Try:

```
instructions = @{@0 : [BRK new]};
```

(This is using the new object primitives which are easier than using dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys)

Answer (score 1):

`typedef unsigned char byte` does not make `byte` into a "class". `byte` aka `char` is just a plain C type, not an object or object type; hence the compiler error.

you either have to box the value into `NSNumber` (or some custom class) as others have suggested, or use [NSMapTable](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSMapTable_class/Reference/NSMapTable.html) as your dictionary which can store arbitrary pointers as both keys and values (not just objective-c objects like `NSDictionary` is limited to).